# Ruby syntax error: unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

**Error:** `/home/g3mini/Desktop/management/app/controllers/user_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end @users is User.all ^`

**code:**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
def index
    @users is User.all
end


def create
end


def store

    @user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:userame,:password))

    @user.save

    redirect_to '/'
end
end
```

Could anyone please tell me what is going wrong?
(total noob here)
Thanks,

g3

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your use of `is` instead of `=`. You should use:
`@users = User.all`

Answer (score 1):

On line number 3

```
@users = User.all
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I made such a noobish mistake hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

The keyword "is" is not valid. I assume that you want @users = User.all

Answer (score 1):

Replace `@users is User.all` by `@users = User.all`